# Отображение queryset в ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, form, queryset

Имею следующую форму.

```
#form
class SotrudnikiForm(forms.Form):
    fio = forms.CharField(max_length=225)
    stepen = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sotrudniki.objects.values('stepen'))

#view
def Sotrudniki(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SotrudnikiForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = SotrudnikiForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post/name.html', {'form': form})

#template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Необходимо чтобы в селекторе отображались данные из бд. Но в результате получаю значение в селекторе {'stepen': 'stepen_1'}. Как можно получить отсюда только значение stepen_1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно использовать `.values()`, запишите просто `Sotrudniki.objects.all()`. В качестве лейбла будет использоваться значение метода `__unicode__`(`__str__` для python3) модели.

```
class Sotrudniki(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stepen

class SotrudnikiForm(forms.Form):

    fio = forms.CharField(max_length=225)
    stepen = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sotrudniki.objects.all())
```

Comment: Все верно. Ранее пытался использовать __str__ но вместе с .values() мне возвращалось не то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Заменить **values** на **values_list**.

Comment: Теперь получаю значение ('stepen_1'), как бы избавиться все таки от лишней информации и получить только само значение?

Comment: Добавить парамет **flat**: values_list('stepen', flat=True)